# How do I pass strings in a "for" statement in bash and send it to a function inside the for as separate arguments?

Tags: string, bash, function, variables, parameters

I want to be able to send resolutions to a function fnToDisplay() from the inside of a for statement. The list in the for statement should be one resolution at a time.

The critical problem is, I cannot modify fnToDIsplay() but should still be able to capture the resolution as separate arguments into this function. Is there any way to accomplish this merely by formatting the for statement or the variable assignemnts in main in a specific way?

Code below doesn't do the intended work but should give an idea of what I am looking for.

```
#!/bin/bash

fnToDisplay()
{
# $1 should display 1280, 1920 and 640 for each call from for loop
echo $1 
# $2 should display 1024, 1080 and 480 for each call from for loop
echo $2
}

res1="1280 1024"
res2="1920 1080"
res3="640 480"
for resolution in $res1 $res2 $res3
do
 fnToDisplay $resolution
done

exit
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just protect $res_i with double quotes when you declare the for cycle:

```
res1="1280 1024"
res2="1920 1080"
res3="640 480"
for resolution in "$res1" "$res2" "$res3"
do
    fnToDisplay $resolution
done
```

By the way, in bash you could have used an array:

```
resolutions=("1280 1024" "1920 1080" "640 480")
for resolution in "${resolutions[@]}"; do
    fnToDisplay $resolution
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you can't beat 'em, join 'em.  If you don't know the number of resolution pairs ahead of time, you can use a here-doc:

```
#!/bin/bash

fnToDisplay()
{
# $1 should display 1280, 1920 and 640 for each call from for loop
echo $1 
# $2 should display 1024, 1080 and 480 for each call from for loop
echo $2
}

res1="1280 1024"
res2="1920 1080"
res3="640 480"

cat <<@EOF | while read resline; do fnToDisplay $resline; done
$res1
$res2
$res3
@EOF

exit
```

Comment: No need for `cat`: `while ... done <<@EOF ...`. No need to have to maintain a correspondence between the variables and the here doc, just put the data directly in the here doc.